# Not able to connect to Oracle Database using Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker, docker-machine, docker-registry

I am deploying my application into a Docker container, on Webspehre liberty server as an EAR file.

However, when the application is running, it cannot connect to the Oracle Database which is running on another host where we are trying to connect through jndi lookup defined in server.xml of Websphere liberty.

```
<dataSource id="oracle" jndiName="jdbc/QADBApp" type="javax.sql.Datasource">

<jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleJDBCLib"/>

<properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xyz.mycomany.com:1521/prexyz" username="****" password="****" />
```

We are able to ping the server from inside the container and getting response but at run time, it is not able to establish the db connection.

Note:- Oracle DB is not containerized. We are simply trying to establish the connection through jndi lookup as mentioned above.

Below is the error message. Could anyone help on how to connect Database in this scenario?Thanks in advance !!

```
[ERROR ] Context initialization failed
Error creating bean with name 'myappFacade': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is      org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private transient com.mycompany.myappTool.service.util.HibernateUtil com.mycompany.myappTool.service.facade.myappToolFacade.hibernateUtil; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateUtil' defined in file [/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/expanded/myapp.ear/myappTool.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/myappTool/service/util/HibernateUtil.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mycompany.myappTool.service.util.HibernateUtil (initialization failure)
[ERROR ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [myapp] in application [myapp]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myappFacade': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private transient com.mycompany.myappTool.service.util.HibernateUtil com.mycompany.myappTool.service.facade.myappToolFacade.hibernateUtil; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateUtil' defined in file [/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/expanded/myapp.ear/myappTool.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/myappTool/service/util/HibernateUtil.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mycompany.myappTool.service.util.HibernateUtil (initialization failure)
```

Comment: Have you checked the classpath and the class is part of library ? And just to confirm, only application is containerized.

Comment: Only application is containerized and running on Websphere liberty server. The same EAR is working fine on WAS console. We checked classes and lib are under WEB-INF as expected.

Answer (score 0):

could you try using ip address instead of xyz.mycomany.com:1521 ? It is definitely a network issue ,you might want to go through https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/
Also you can try from inside your container cat /etc/hosts
it should list the ip/machine you want to connect to.